# Add user input of string into a list using blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I've been tasked to add a string entered by a user from a form into a list of string using blazor. From what I can tell you're unable to bind-Value a list as it only accepts type string.

As I can only bind one value to the text box I'm not able to have multiple user inputs that can go into the list.

Is there a way that I'm able to enter the user input into a list, then enter more user input into the same list, but only using the one variable assigned to the bind-Value parameter?

Comment: Why not add a button? If you have a list, then you'd bind to the last item in the list. Use the button to add a new entry in the list.

Comment: Could you show us what you have all ready tried and what is going wrong, without that all we could do is link to the blazor docs

Comment: The string entered by the user, should it be split on a specific separator (e.g. newline or comma)? Then maybe you can define a data-bound property of type string, with the setter calling `string.Split`, and the getter calling `string.Join`.

Comment: Search for Blazor Todo, I'm sure you'll find hundreds of examples

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually get the items from the Input and add them to the List.

One way to achieve this is to listen for specific Key events using `@onkeydown`.

In the example below, whenever the user presses `Enter` we'll take whatever was typed into the `Input` and add it to the list, then clear the input so the user can enter more items.

```
@page "/"

<input @bind-value="UserInput" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeydown="CheckInput"></input>

<h2>My List</h2>

@foreach (var item in myList)
{
    <h3>@item</h3>
}

@code {

    private string UserInput { get; set; }
    public List<string> myList = new List<string> { "ItemOne" };

    private void CheckInput(KeyboardEventArgs keyEvent)
    {
        if(keyEvent.Key == "Enter")
        {
            AddToList(UserInput);
            UserInput = string.Empty;
        }

    }

    private void AddToList(string str)
    {
        myList.Add(str);
    }
}
```